# why is handleChange function applied to all the elements being mapped in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion, onchange, map-function

I am using accordion from mui where I am using `map()` function to add data to each accordion. For `onChange` event of a particular accordion, `handleChange` is be called because of which that accordion should expand, but all the accordions are been expanded rather than the one for which the handleChange is called! How to fix this?

Code for handle change:

```
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState('panel1');

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    console.log(panel);
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };
```

Code returned inside react component:

```
   <Container sx={{ paddingBlock: "4rem" }}>
      {faqData.map((faq, index) =>
        <Accordion key={index} expanded={expanded === ('panel' + { index })} onChange={handleChange('panel' + { index })}>
          <AccordionSummary aria-controls={('panel' + { index } + 'd - content')} id={('panel' + { index } + 'd-header')}>
            <Typography>{faq[0]}</Typography>
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>
              {faq[1]}
            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      )}
    </Container>
```

Comment: handleChange('panel' + { index }) 

should be 

() => handleChange('panel' + { index })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you construct the expression for the `expanded` property as well as the argument to the `handleChange` function.

What happens is that `'panel' + {index}` evaluates to `'panel[object Object]'` string, **the same** for all panels.

You can achieve the desired result by using string interpolation instead:

```
        <Accordion
          key={index}
          expanded={expanded === `panel${index}`}
          onChange={handleChange(`panel${index}`)}
        >
```

You can see a live demo in this [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fqeyvv).

Answer (score 0):

in the below line of code , you are executing the handleChange function for every item of the map, that's why you are not getting the desired results

```
<Accordion key={index} expanded={expanded === ('panel' + { index })} onChange={handleChange('panel' + { index })}
```

Rather, you should pass the reference of the handle change function and use bind() to pass in the arguments

```
<Accordion key={index} expanded={expanded === ('panel' + { index })} onChange={handleChange.bind(...pass-arguments-here)}
```